# Redeclaration of the method "in" within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, adt

I am creating an Abstract Data Type, which create a doubly linked list (not sure it's the correct translation). In it I have create a method __len__ to calcucate the length of it in the correct way, a method __repr__ to represent it correctly, but I wan't now to create a method which, when the user will make something like:

```
if foo in liste_adt
```

will return the correct answer, but I don't know what to use, because __in__ is not working.

Thank you,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you looking for [`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)?

> `object.__contains__(self, item)`
>
> > Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if *item* is in *self,* false otherwise. For mapping objects, this should consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the key-item pairs.
> >
> > For objects that don’t define [**`__contains__()`**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__), the membership test first tries iteration via [**`__iter__()`**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__), then the old sequence iteration protocol via [**`__getitem__()`**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), see [*this section in the language reference*](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).

Quick example:

```
>>> class Bar:
...     def __init__(self, iterable):
...         self.list = list(iterable)
...     def __contains__(self, item):
...         return item in self.list
>>>     
>>> b = Bar([1,2,3])
>>> b.list
[1, 2, 3]
>>> 4 in b
False
>>> 2 in b
True
```

**Note:** Usually when you have this kind of doubts references can be found in the [**Data Model**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) section of the [The Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/index.html).

Comment: it is exactly what I was looking for, thanks, and thanks for the documentation link, i was searching for this before posting the question

Comment: @kasmanit: You're welcome! That is section of the PLR that I visit more often. *(I always forget what's the actual name of something)* :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the data structure is a linked list, it is necessary to iterate over it to check membership. Implementing an  `__iter__()` method would make both `if in` and `for in` work. If there is a more efficient way for checking membership, implement that in `__contains__()`.