# How to use tuples as parameters for __getitem__()?

Tags: python, duck-typing

I'm writing a custom class that wraps a dict. As such, I want to implement **getitem** for it. I also will be using tuples as keys in this dict. However, when I try to pass a tuple to getitem, Python throws a KeyError. It looks like it's casting my tuple to an int when I pass it to **getitem**:

Code:

```
Class Board(object):
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    print "type in call: " + type(key)
    return self.board[key]

# in main somewhere
board = Board()

print "type before call: " + type((1, 2))
if (1, 2) in board:
  print "It's there!"
```

Ouptut:

```
type before call: <type 'tuple'>
type in call: <type 'int'>

## traceback stuff ##
KeyError: 0
```

Does Board need to inherit from a mapping type for Python to be happy? Also, why does Python try to do this cast in the first place?

Comment: You are trying to implement a membership test, take a look at [Redeclaration of the method "in" within a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9428419/1132524).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containment iterates unless `__contains__()` is implemented. So, implement it.

Comment: Maybe you want to rephrase your first sentence, since it's not true: [`__contains__` doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

Comment: @Rik: "For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`..."

Comment: Alternatively, subclass one of the [collection ABCs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) and let Python implement the boring parts for you.